# Combining REs that can match multiple messy stock entries

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use REs to clean up a string and put them into a clean ordered list of stocks while preserving the original order or not repeating stocks.

For example turn the string **(Note the extra random letters and the inconsistent spacing)**:

```
SLTD +14% NRX +14%L MEIP -68% YU -345% RXII -13%RESN -10% LBIO -10% WHLR-10% HSIDD -339%
```

Into a list like

```
stocks = ['SLTD +14%', 'NRX +14%', 'MEIP -68%', 'YU -345%', 'RXII -13%','RESN -10%', 'LBIO -10%', 'WHLR -10%', 'HSIDD -339%']
```

I need the REs to

1. Pick out 2,3,4 or 5 uppercase letters (the ticker) (without out relying on the space in front, as cases such as this `RXII -13%RESN -10%` would fail)
2. Recognize if there is a space between the last letter of the ticker and the + or -, and if not insert one. (to clean up cases like this `WHLR-10%`)
3. Not include random letters after the % (such as `NRX +14%L`)
4. Not include a stock if there is only ticker and no percentage (i.e. `NES -14% HELI`)
5. Be able to handle both 2 digit and 3 digit percentages (`WHLR-10% HSIDD -339%`)

This is the best I have got so far, it repeats every stock with 4, then 3, then 2 letters and is of course awful code.

Any help would be very much appreciated,
Thank you for your time.

```
allStocks = ['SLTD +14% NRX +14%L MEIP -68% YU -345% RXII -13%RESN -10% LBIO -10% WHLR-10% HSIDD -339%','ENZ -17% NSLP -17% SCON -15% PKOH -15% PFIE -14% PRTS -14% NES -14% HELI']

for messyDayOfStocks in allStocks:
    stocksWithStuff = re.findall('(\S\S\S\S\S\s\D\d\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks")
    stocksWithStuff.append(re.findall('(\S\S\S\S\s\D\d\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks"))
    stocksWithStuff.append(re.findall('(\S\S\S\s\D\d\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks"))
    stocksWithStuff.append(re.findall('(\S\S\s\D\d\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks"))
    stocksWithStuff.append(re.findall('(\S\S\S\S\S\s\D\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks"))
    stocksWithStuff.append(re.findall('(\S\S\S\S\s\D\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks"))
    stocksWithStuff.append(re.findall('(\S\S\S\s\D\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks"))
    stocksWithStuff.append(re.findall('(\S\S\s\D\d\d%)', "messyDayOfStocks"))     
    print(stocksWithStuff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use this:

```
import re

allStocks = ['SLTD +14% NRX +14%L MEIP -68% YU -345% RXII -13%RESN -10% LBIO -10% WHLR-10% HSIDD -339%','ENZ -17% NSLP -17% SCON -15% PKOH -15% PFIE -14% PRTS -14% NES -14% HELI']
stocksWithStuff = []

for messyDayOfStocks in allStocks:
    # Get each match 
    for match in re.finditer(r"([A-Z]{2,5})\s*([-+]?\d{2,3}%)", messyDayOfStocks):
        # Format it
        stocksWithStuff.append("{0} {1}".format(match.group(1), match.group(2)))

print(stocksWithStuff)
```

Outputs:

```
['SLTD +14%', 'NRX +14%', 'MEIP -68%', 'YU -345%', 'RXII -13%', 'RESN -10%', 'LBIO -10%', 'WHLR -10%', 'HSIDD -339%', 'ENZ -17%', 'NSLP -17%', 'SCON -15%', 'PKOH -15%', 'PFIE -14%', 'PRTS -14%', 'NES -14%']
```

the above is using Python3 but it should be easily converted to Python2 syntax.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/pjl0fT)

For the regex itself:

```
([A-Z]{2,5})  # 2 to 5 uppercase letters and store in first group
\s*           # Any number of spaces (including none)
(
  [-+]?       # Any sign if present
  \d{2,3}%    # 2 to 3 digits and % sign
)             # Store the above to the second group
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `(\S{2,5}\s?[+-]\d{1,3}%)`

This looks for:

- `\S{2,5}` between 2 and 5 non whitespace characters
- `\s?` a possible whitespace character
- `[+-]` either a plus or minus sign
- `\d{1,3}` between 1 and 3 digits
- `%` a percent sign

[Link to regextester](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5CS%7B2%2C5%7D%5Cs%3F%5B%2B-%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%25)&test_string=stocks%20%3D%20%5B%27SLTD%20%2B14%25%27%2C%20%27NRX%20%2B14%25%27%2C%20%27MEIP%20-68%25%27%2C%20%27YU%20-345%25%27%2C%20%27RXII%20-13%25%27%2C%27RESN%20-10%25%27%2C%20%27LBIO%20-10%25%27%2C%20%27WHLR%20-10%25%27%2C%20%27HSIDD%20-339%25%27%5D%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

This won't insert a space for you, but you could use 2 capture groups instead like this:

[`(\S{2,5})\s?([+-]\d{1,3}%)`](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5CS%7B2%2C5%7D)%5Cs%3F(%5B%2B-%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%25)&test_string=stocks%20%3D%20%5B%27SLTD%20%2B14%25%27%2C%20%27NRX%20%2B14%25%27%2C%20%27MEIP%20-68%25%27%2C%20%27YU%20-345%25%27%2C%20%27RXII%20-13%25%27%2C%27RESN%20-10%25%27%2C%20%27LBIO%20-10%25%27%2C%20%27WHLR%20-10%25%27%2C%20%27HSIDD%20-339%25%27%5D%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)
to get the company id and percentage separately

You can use this in your code as:

```
allStocks = ['SLTD +14% NRX +14%L MEIP -68% YU -345% RXII -13%RESN -10% LBIO -10% WHLR-10% HSIDD -339%','ENZ -17% NSLP -17% SCON -15% PKOH -15% PFIE -14% PRTS -14% NES -14% HELI']

for messyDayOfStocks in allStocks:
    allMatches = re.findall('(\S{2,5})\s?([+-]\d{1,3}%)', messyDayOfStocks)
    stocks = ['{} {}'.format(m.group(1), m.group(2) for m in allMatches]
    print(stocks)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you. In this code, I find the pattern, append the formatted output to the list and then starts again the search specifying the starting position of the search as the end of the last search.

```
astr = 'SLTD +14% NRX +14%L MEIP -68% YU -345% RXII -13%RESN -10% LBIO -10% WHLR-10% HSIDD -339%'
out = []
pat = '([A-Z]{2,5}) ?(\+|-)(\d{2,3}\%)'
regex = re.compile(pat)
res = regex.search(astr)
while res:
    out.append(res.group(1)+' '+res.group(2)+res.group(3))
    res = regex.search(astr, res.start()+len(res.group(0)))
print out
# prints ['SLTD +14%', 'NRX +14%', 'MEIP -68%', 'YU -345%', 'RXII -13%', 'RESN -10%', 'LBIO -10%', 'WHLR -10%', 'HSIDD -339%']
```